How to read the source code of a Maven dependency's JAR?
I'm writing a Maven plugin that parses the source code of the project where this plugin is called, and generates documentation based on certain rules.
Now I have a question: when I have the source code of class A (including its comments) and I found that class A references another class B, how can I get the source code of class B?
Class B may be in the same directory, in a different directory, or even in a Maven dependency's JAR.
Of course, the dependency JAR may have been generated with the maven-source-plugin, in which case I should be able to get its source code, right?
Can anyone give me some ideas or solutions on how to implement this requirement?

First by default jar's do not contain source code... only compiled classes and resources... the source code could be contained in sources jar which means it is named like artifactId-version-sources.jar (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/3.3.0/) but it is not neccessary... most packaged on central have those supplemental classifier-based packages but not all of them.. In such cases you need to solve the dependency based on the classifier... but the question what kind of source code documentation you are talking about?

"... in which case I should be able to get its source code, right?"  - Not necessarily.  The publisher can upload the JAR file containing the bytecodes to a repository without providing any access to the real source code.  And even if the source code was available to start with, there is no real guarantee that it will always be available.  (You cannot enforce the terms of the GPL against a company that has gone out of business!)

It don't think that there is a solution that is going to work with a high probability.  It is simpler to leave the problem of locating the source code for dependencies to the programmer.  (Otherwise you will for ever be dealing with whinges that your plugin "doesn't work".)
